# How to perform upcasting in web services REST jersey?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I am trying to perform upcasting in REST web services. But I am getting 400 bad request in the response. How can I perform upcasting in web services.

```
@XmlRootElement
Class Animal{
String type;
...
}

@XmlRootElement
Class Tiger extends Animal{
String name;
...
}
    SERVER SIDE:
    ===========
    @POST
        @Path("/upcasting")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        public void testUpcasting(@FormDataParam("an") Animal anml){
            System.out.println("inside testupcasting");
            System.out.println(anml.getClass());
        }

    CLIENT SIDE:
    ===========
String uri = "http://localhost:8080/app/upcasting";
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
            Client client = Client.create(config);

            WebResource resource = client.resource(uri);

            Tiger t = new Tiger();
            t.setType("Non-veg");
            t.setName("myTiger");

            FormDataMultiPart multipart = new FormDataMultiPart().field("an", t, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);

                ClientResponse response = resource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).post(ClientResponse.class, multipart);
```

Comment: I got the answer by putting @XmlSeeAlso(Tiger.class) annotation at Animla class.

Answer (score 0):

SERVER:

```
@POST
@Path("/upcasting")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public void testUpcasting(Animal anml){
     System.out.println("inside testupcasting");
     System.out.println(anml.getClass());
}
```

CLIENT:

```
String URL = "http://......./rest/services
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
target = client.target(URL);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Response response = target.path("/upcasting").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(Entity.entity(mapper.writeValueAsString(anml), MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
```